# Old website has lots of index.php URLs indexed. How to redirect before Magento rewrites?

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Looks like Magento redirects anything with index.php in the URL straight to the home page if you're using SEO friendly URLs. The issue is that we have an old website that has a ton of URLs indexed that look like this: /index.php?route=product/product&product_id=70

So 301 redirects in the htaccess file do not work and I also tried adding the URLs to Magento Admin's URL Rewrite Management with no luck. Is there any way to make this work?

Example, this is what I'm currently doing that doesn't work thanks to the index.php:

```
redirect 301 /index.php?route=product/product&product_id=70 http://www.bosu.com/bosu-sports-conditioning-football
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `Redirect` directive, you'll need to use either the `%{QUERY_STRING}` or `%{THE_REQUEST}` variables inside a rewrite condition. Note that `Redirect` is part of mod_alias, which is separate from mod_rewrite, and both modules will get applied to the same request. So if you're using both, there's a good chance the directives could interfere with each other.

Try adding this *before* any rules related to magento:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?route=product/product&product_id=70($|&|\ )
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.bosu.com/bosu-sports-conditioning-football? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like that before too, but it ends up in a redirect loop - that ends up changing the url to http://www.bosu.com/bosu-sports-conditioning-football?route=product/product&product_id=70

Comment: @joren AH, forgot the `?` at the end of the URL

Comment: I could kiss you. THANK YOU